# If I have a four monitor display how do I move applications to certain monitors in python?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI using tkinter where you can select applications and then select what screen/monitor you want to open them on.

I was originally going to use windows layout manager using `os.system` to open the application, waiting for the application to open, and then opening the command prompt and running the layout for that specific application using `os system('cmd /c "WinLayoutManager.exe {layout name}"')`.

It looked like this:

```
mission_planner_clicked = tkinter.IntVar()
mission_planner_check = ttk.Checkbutton(window, text="Mission Planner", variable=mission_planner_clicked)
mission_planner_check.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)


def click():
    if mission_planner_clicked.get():
        os.system(r"C:\Users\red\Desktop\MissionPlanner.exe")
        time.sleep(10)
        os.system('cmd /c "WinLayoutManager.exe MissionPlanner"')


start_up = ttk.Button(window, text="Click to start", command=click).grid(row=10, column=0)
```

Then I realized that was inefficient.

Now I am trying to figure out a way to select an application and then select what screen you want it on like so:

[Image of my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp7hW.jpg)

The only problem I'm having is I don't know how to move an application to a certain screen/monitor using python commands. Is there a certain plugin/module and certain commands I should use to map each monitor to a screen. This way I can click Mission Planner, Screen 1, and Click to Start to send the application Mission Planner to Monitor/Screen 1.

Comment: Have you tried using the `wm_geometry` method?

Comment: @BryanOakley No, what is the `wm_geometry` method?